# how can playing video within webView in swift

Tags: webview, swift3

i have an issue for playing video from youtube within webView i try to playing video from youtube not in full screen in webView but i couldn't and i set the the property  allowsInlineMediaPlayback for webView in viewDidLoad()  but it's not working

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

  let url = URL(string: "http://www.youtube.com")
        let YOUTUBE =  URLRequest(url:url!)
        webView.loadRequest(YOUTUBEURL)
   webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
}
```

so please can help me for how can i playing video youtube not in full screen in webView

thanks A lot

Answer (score 0):

you should use UIWebView instead of WKWebView.

here is the needed code for you:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var myWebView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myWebView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true

    myWebView.loadHTMLString("<iframe width=\"\(myWebView.frame.width)\" height=\"\(myWebView.frame.height)\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/FDT343j3zD0?playsinline=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", baseURL: nil)
}
}
```